# displaying TimeZone in android

Tags: java, android

I have implemented the below code in my app to display the date and time with timezone.

```
    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a z");
    sdformat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
    System.out.println(sdformat.format(d));
```

If I run the above code in eclipse, I get the output as:

> 11/13/2015 07:23:56 PM EST

But for the same code in android device, I get the output as:

> 11/13/2015 07:23:56 PM GMT-5.00

Why is the difference, I need the date format to be displayed as:

> 11/13/2015 07:23:56 PM EST

Comment: try setLenient(false) http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)

Comment: setLenient(false) didn't solve the issue. @DanielFigueroa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TimeZone.getTimeZone(String id)` is designed to use so-called Olson format among others as a parameter. Details you can find [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone%28java.lang.String%29).

EST time corresponds to the value `"America/New_York"`, so

```
sdformat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
```

will give the expected result.

Comment: it worked. thank you so much @DimitryArc